# Disconnected title page?

Tags: sectioning, formatting, chapters

I'm trying to find a way to have a full page "title" type page before the start of every chapter. However, the chapter name will be on the first page of the chapter as well. The title text will be different on the full title page before each chapter and I don't really want the title page to affect the chapter page numbers or anything like that. Here is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish. Just a simple page with a two or three line title (depends on the chapter name).

The left image is what I'm looking for. I have the first page of each chapter setup already. and both of these are right pages. excuse the mockup image, i failed to include a blank page between them.

And to be clear, this title page would be a right facing page, un numbered. So blank page << >> title page, blank page << >> chapter start...

[image]

```
% UNIVERSAL SETTINGS
\documentclass[statementpaper,10pt,twoside,onecolumn,openright,extrafontsizes]{memoir} % set page properties
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % set displayable characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[osf]{Alegreya,AlegreyaSans} % set font face
\usepackage{canoniclayout} % canonical margins, breaks page number?
\usepackage{subfiles} % to pull chapter files in from other sub files
\usepackage{lipsum}

% INDEX SETTINGS
% run "makeindex index_name.idx -s style.ist" in terminal to generate each correct index files before typesetting
\makeindex[genesis]
\makeindex[exodus]
\makeindex[leviticus]

% TABLE OF CONTENTS SETTINGS
\renewcommand{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}% Chapters should use dots in TOC
%\usepackage{patchcmd} % set width
%\makeatletter % set width
%\patchcommand\@starttoc{\begin{quote}}{\end{quote}} % set width
%\makeatother % set width

% CHAPTER SETTINGS
\renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{\centering}
\renewcommand*{\printchapternonum}{\centering}

% PAGE HEADER SETTINGS
\nouppercaseheads % prevent all uppercase header titles
\makeatletter % put chapter title on both pages
\createmark{chapter}{both}{shownumber}{\@chapapp\ }{. \ } % put chapter title on both pages
\makeatother % put chapter title on both pages

% PARAPGRAPH SETTINGS
\usepackage{ragged2e} % indent paragraphs using ragged right
\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{\parindent} % indent paragraphs with ragged right
\raggedbottom % avoid paragraph spacing issues but allow bottom ragged lines
\usepackage{lettrine} % for drop caps and awesome chapter beginnings
\linespread{1.2} % line-height

\renewcommand{\chapternumberline}[1]{}% Gobble chapter number in ToC
\renewcommand{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}% Chapter dots in ToC

% TITLE PAGE FORMATTING
% creates the title page and printed title text
\newlength\drop
\newcommand*{\titleMain}{%
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begingroup% Gentle Madness
\drop = 0.1\textheight
\vspace*{\baselineskip}
\vfill
\hbox{%
%\hspace*{0.2\textwidth}%
%\rule{1pt}{\dimexpr\textheight-28pt\relax}%
%\hspace*{0.05\textwidth}%
\parbox[b]{1.0\textwidth}{
\vbox{%
\vspace{\drop}
\centering{\noindent\HUGE\bfseries Holy Bible}\\[2\baselineskip]
{\Large King James Version}\\[.37\baselineskip]
{\Large\itshape Authorized Edition}
\vspace{0.5\textheight}
%{\noindent The Publisher}\\[\baselineskip]
}% end of vbox
}% end of parbox
}% end of hbox
\vfill
\null
\endgroup}

% BEGIN THE DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
\titleMain % print title page created in preamble
\cleardoublepage % blank page after title and TOC page

% TABLE OF CONTENTS
\begin{center} % center the TOC title text
\tableofcontents* % print table of contents page
\end{center}
\thispagestyle{empty} % hide page number header on TOC page

% BEGIN MAIN CONTENT MATTER
\cleardoublepage % restart page numbers

\RaggedRight % apply ragged right paragraph format
\pagenumbering{arabic} % change page numbering to numbers

\subfile{tex/genesis} % print text from chapter files
\subfile{tex/exodus}
\subfile{tex/leviticus}


% BEGING BACK CONTENT MATTER
\backmatter

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textit {Index of Chapters}} % for consolidating index in TOC
{\def\addcontentsline#1#2#3{} % for consolidating index in TOC

 % INDEX
\clearpage
% \renewcommand{\preindexhook}{}
% \twocolindex
\renewcommand{\indexname}{Genesis}
\printindex[genesis]
\renewcommand{\indexname}{Exodus}
\printindex[exodus]
\renewcommand{\indexname}{Leviticus}
\printindex[leviticus]

\end{document}
% END OF DOCUMENT
```

And the subfile.

```
\begin{document}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Genesis} % manually adds TOC entry if you hide title on first page of chapter
\markboth{Genesis}{Genesis} % Correct headers after manually setting TOC
\chapter*{Genesis} % add asterisk after "chapter" and remove "Gensis" from brackets to hide chapter title on first page of chapter

\index[genesis]{Chapter 1}\lettrine[lines=3]{N}{}ow these \lipsum
\index[genesis]{Chapter 2} \lipsum
\index[genesis]{Chapter 3} \lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Your code depends on at least three subfiles. Which is the one you have provided and which are the ones we are meant to use our crystal balls to guess? Please try to minimise your code so that you include just what is needed to reproduce the problem. But remember, we need to compile your code. If you call files we don't have, we can't.

Comment: You shouldn't be using the `center` environment around the table of contents.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question correctly: Do you want to have a title page right before **every** chapter (here: Genesis, Exodus, Leviticus), or one title page followed by several chapters? On the preview you gave above, would `Chapter Name` be the same as `MainTitle`?

Comment: This question can do with some re-wording to just ask the essentials...

Comment: i couldn't get the toc title to center without the center environment. is there something I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your code so that **every** chapter is preceded with a title page. The formatting is done by the new command `\tpchapter`. You should change the block inside the `center`environment -- in its current state, it is rather sketchy, just an ugly proof-of-concept sort of thing. :-)

I've also included the package `hyperref` (no options set yet) so `\phantomsection` is available. I guess it makes sense to insert `\phantomsection` on the chapter's title page, but you could move it right before the line with `\chapter*{#2}`.

Here is the code (like StefanH did in his answer, I dropped one chapter and moved the example text from subfiles into the main document, so the document compiles without any hassle):

```
% UNIVERSAL SETTINGS
\documentclass[statementpaper,10pt,twoside,onecolumn,openright,extrafontsizes]{memoir} % set page properties
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % set displayable characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[osf]{Alegreya,AlegreyaSans} % set font face
\usepackage{canoniclayout} % canonical margins, breaks page number?
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}      % provides \phantomsection

% INDEX SETTINGS
% run "makeindex index_name.idx -s style.ist" in terminal to generate each correct index files before typesetting
\makeindex[genesis]
\makeindex[exodus]

% TABLE OF CONTENTS SETTINGS
\renewcommand{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}% Chapters should use dots in TOC

% CHAPTER SETTINGS
\renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{\centering}
\renewcommand*{\printchapternonum}{\centering}

% PAGE HEADER SETTINGS
\nouppercaseheads % prevent all uppercase header titles
\makeatletter % put chapter title on both pages
\createmark{chapter}{both}{shownumber}{\@chapapp\ }{. \ } % put chapter title on both pages
\makeatother % put chapter title on both pages

% PARAPGRAPH SETTINGS
\usepackage{ragged2e} % indent paragraphs using ragged right
\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{\parindent} % indent paragraphs with ragged right
\raggedbottom % avoid paragraph spacing issues but allow bottom ragged lines
\usepackage{lettrine} % for drop caps and awesome chapter beginnings
\linespread{1.2} % line-height

\renewcommand{\chapternumberline}[1]{}% Gobble chapter number in ToC
\renewcommand{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}% Chapter dots in ToC

% TITLE PAGE FORMATTING
% creates the title page and printed title text
\newlength\drop
\newcommand*{\titleMain}{%
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begingroup% Gentle Madness
\drop = 0.1\textheight
\vspace*{\baselineskip}
\vfill
\hbox{%
\parbox[b]{1.0\textwidth}{
\vbox{%
\vspace{\drop}
\centering{\noindent\HUGE\bfseries Holy Bible}\\[2\baselineskip]
{\Large King James Version}\\[.37\baselineskip]
{\Large\itshape Authorized Edition}
\vspace{0.5\textheight}
}% end of vbox
}% end of parbox
}% end of hbox
\vfill
\null
\endgroup}

% Formatting macros for Pre title, Main title and Sub title
\newcommand{\tppretitle}[1]{{\LARGE\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\tpmaintitle}[1]{{\Huge\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\tpsubtitle}[1]{{\LARGE\textbf{#1}}}

% Macro to typeset the sequence "[empty page] --> title page --> empty page --> chapter"
% #1: Pre title    #2: Main title (== chapter name)    #3 Sub title    #4 Label
\newcommand{\tpchapter}[4]{%
    \cleardoublepage%

    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \vspace*{\fill}%
    \phantomsection%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2}%
    \label{#4}

% Adjust the format of the chapter titlepage in this block
    \begin{center}
    \tppretitle{#1}\\[\baselineskip]
    \tpmaintitle{#2}\\[\baselineskip]
    \tpsubtitle{#3}%
    \end{center}
    \vfill%


    \cleardoublepage%
    \chapter*{#2}
    \thispagestyle{plain}%
    \markboth{#2}{#2}%
 }

% BEGIN THE DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
\titleMain % print title page created in preamble
\cleardoublepage % blank page after title and TOC page

% TABLE OF CONTENTS
\tableofcontents* % print table of contents page
\thispagestyle{empty} % hide page number header on TOC page

% BEGIN MAIN CONTENT MATTER
\cleardoublepage % restart page numbers

\RaggedRight % apply ragged right paragraph format
\pagenumbering{arabic} % change page numbering to numbers


%***TEXT starts here***
\tpchapter{Pre title}{Genesis}{Subtitle}{cha:genesis}
\index[genesis]{Chapter 1}\lettrine[lines=3]{N}{}ow these \lipsum
\index[genesis]{Chapter 2}\lettrine[lines=3]{N}{}ow these \lipsum
\index[genesis]{Chapter 3}\lettrine[lines=3]{N}{}ow these \lipsum

\tpchapter{Pre title}{Exodus}{Subtitle}{cha:exodus}
\index[exodus]{Chapter 1}\lettrine[lines=3]{N}{}ow these \lipsum
\index[exodus]{Chapter 2}\lettrine[lines=3]{N}{}ow these \lipsum
\index[exodus]{Chapter 3}\lettrine[lines=3]{N}{}ow these \lipsum


% BEGING BACK CONTENT MATTER
\backmatter

%% INDEX
\begin{center}\vspace*{\fill}
    \phantomsection\thispagestyle{empty}
    \tpmaintitle{Index of Chapters}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textit {Index of Chapters}} % for consolidating index in TOC
    \label{cha:ioc}
    \vfill
\end{center}

\renewcommand{\indexname}{Genesis}
\printindex[genesis]
\renewcommand{\indexname}{Exodus}
\printindex[exodus]

\end{document}
```

Comment: sorry, yes, i though i was more clear. updated the question to reflect this. i have a title page, but i couldn't get it to work before every chapter. i will try the suggestion and report back. thanks.

Comment: It seems to be removing my first page page number at the bottom. Also, the formatting of the title page is very wide spread and all the same font size... is there a way to keep my subfiles and do something similar with customizable text size/placement? I'll look into more. Thanks for all the help so far... Having the text in the main document (even split into chapter sections) would be incredibly difficult for me to manage...

Comment: @luisdent About the missing pagenumber: I just changed the pagestyle to `plain` in the last block of the definition of `\tpchapter`. Also, in the block marked `% Adjust the format of the chapter titlepage in this block` I replaced `\vfill` with `\\[\baselineskip]` and changed the font sizes. Feel free to play around and change the formatting of the chapter's title page to your liking!

About the subfiles: Sure, leave all your text there -- nothing wrong with that! Just use `\tpchapter{pretitle}{main title}{subtitle}{label}` whenever you start a new chapter.

Comment: @luisdent I just like to have everything in one place when working on such examples -- spreading **dummy text** over several input files if you just want see a rough draft doesn't make much sense. (It's a different story if you want to explain different methods to insert text from external files, of course. Actually, I didn't know about the `subfiles` package before and used only `\input{}` or `\include{}`  -- what I read about it in the documentation looks really practical, though. I guess I will use it myself from now on!)

Comment: awesome. thanks. i'll double check everything tonight and post back. :-)

Comment: Awesome! That all works great! The only thing left is a title page for the index. If I used the same solution it adds two extra blank pages (4 total). I'm assuming it thinks it's a chapter and thus adds a clear double page, but I removed the cleardouble from the index, but it still quadruples the pages. Any way around that for the index? Or does it require a different solution? I tried duplicating the macro and renaming it tpindex and removing the cleardouble. no luck.

Comment: @luisdent I'll look at that tonight -- quite busy right now!

Comment: it does look like the index is making it's own title page. so i'd need to know how to format that or hid that entire page set...

Comment: @luisdent Well, `printindex` makes its own chapter heading, so `\tpchapter` prints a superfluous set of pages. Also, `\backmatter`  calls `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage`. So perhaps it would be easier to format the Index of Chapters manually -- unless you have more cases like this, then it would make sense to put everything into a second macro.

Comment: @luisdent I have added three formatting macros (for selecting the font of pre, main, and sub title) before `\tpchapter` and manually inserted the title page for the Index of Chapters. There, I used `\tpmaintitle` to ensure the heading on the title page is in the same font as the chapter titles on the title pages produced by `\tpchapter`.

Comment: Thanks, your solutions work great. I have simply called the tpsubtitle and baselineskip in the index section as well to get subtitle text and it all works perfectly!. Solved.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question right you are looking for a way to typeset the title page. As the code for the title page is given in the MWE there are IMO too many unnecessary boxes. I would do something like this.

```
% TITLE PAGE FORMATTING
% creates the title page and printed title text
\newcommand*{\titleMain}{%
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \centering% In case the title widths below are changed
  \rule{0pt}{6em}
  \parbox{\linewidth}{\centering\LARGE\MyPreTitle}
  \rule{0pt}{1em}
  \parbox{\linewidth}{\centering\HUGE\bfseries\MyMainTitle}
  \rule{0pt}{1em}
  \parbox{\linewidth}{\centering\Large\MySubTitle}
  \cleardoublepage
} 
\newcommand\MyPreTitle{}
\newcommand\MyMainTitle{}
\newcommand\MySubTitle{}
\newcommand\PreTitle[1]{\renewcommand\MyPreTitle{#1}}
\newcommand\MainTitle[1]{\renewcommand\MyMainTitle{#1}}
\newcommand\SubTitle[1]{\renewcommand\MySubTitle{#1}}

% BEGIN THE DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
\PreTitle{This is my pre-title}
\MainTitle{Main title}
\SubTitle{Sub-title}
\titleMain % print title page

% TABLE OF CONTENTS
\tableofcontents* % print table of contents page
\thispagestyle{empty} % hide page number header on TOC page
\cleardoublepage

% BEGIN MAIN CONTENT MATTER
\RaggedRight % apply ragged right paragraph format
\pagenumbering{arabic} % change page numbering to numbers

\chapter*{Genesis} % add asterisk after "chapter" and remove "Gensis" from brackets to hide chapter title on first page of chapter
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Genesis} % manually adds TOC entry if you hide title on first page of chapter
\markboth{Genesis}{Genesis} % Correct headers after manually setting TOC
\lipsum[1-8]

\chapter*{Exodus} % add asterisk after "chapter" and remove "Gensis" from brackets to hide chapter title on first page of chapter
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Exodus} % manually adds TOC entry if you hide title on first page of chapter
\markboth{Exodus}{Exodus} % Correct headers after manually setting TOC
\lipsum[1-8]
```

I have added two chapters instead of the external files. By putting the title page as the first page it ends up on the right side in a double sided format. So there should not be a blank page first as indicated in the question.

[image]

Comment: I was able to use your solution, but simply place it in each subfile and rename the "titleMain" to "titleGensis", etc. And it appears to be working. Any reason not to do that?

Comment: @luisdent, Now I am a bit confused for what your are looking for. If the title page is in fact the chapter heading that is not how I understood the question. But anyway, you can reuse the `\titleMain` several times, just use `\PreTitle{...}`, `\MainTitle{...}` and `\SubTitle{...}` to set the titles. So you don't need a new title page definition for each chapter. And you might want to add the chapter to the ToC.

Comment: This is also a good solution for the main title page, but the other example is more complete. Thanks.